# Flow - how to use declared type in another type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

```
import type {crusherDowntimeRecord} from "./downtime/types";

type Props = {
  data: Array<crusherDowntimeRecord>,
};
type State = {
  rows: Props.data,
};
```

On `Props.data` Flow throws:

> Error:(30, 15) Cannot get Props.data because property data is missing in  Props [1].

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `data` through `Props` because it's `type`, not `javascript object`.
For solution use *flow* `$PropertyType`:

```
import type {CrusherDowntimeRecord} from "./downtime/types";

type Props = {
  data: Array<CrusherDowntimeRecord>,
};

type State = {
  rows: $PropertyType<Props, 'data'>,
};
```

[Flow - Property type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-propertytype)

[FlowTry - Example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAKATnDgM5gC8YA3qmGACYCGGLAXGAILHEtYAPCwB2WAHwAaVAF902fGADK7DARq0APgzCkE5LgBISZPMWwAVXHkEmKksAHJW7R1NSa56AMZwR5DDA8AA8WAFscGDwuFTZ1Ol1EAzAAbQBdMBkAblQgA)